# Add QWidget or other QWidget derived controls into QWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

`QtGUI` and `QtWidgets` have been separated in Qt5.

How can I add `QWidget` or other `QWidget` derived controls into `QWindow`?

Comment: Add QT += widgets in pro file and add QWidget in designer or in code. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Why not take a `QMainWindow` which is in widgets module. From the docs: An application will typically use QWidget or QQuickView for its UI, and not QWindow directly. Still, it is possible to render directly to a QWindow with QBackingStore or QOpenGLContext, when wanting to keep dependencies to a minimum or when wanting to use OpenGL directly. The Raster Window Example and OpenGL Window Example are useful reference examples for how to render to a QWindow using either approach.

Answer (score 0):

A `QWindow` is not meant to be used that way. Instead of using a `QWindow` directly, you need a `QWidget` instead. A parentless `QWidget` by default becomes a top-level window.

If you have a particular reason to use a `QWindow`, you'll have to edit your question to provide details on your design; most likely your design is incorrect.